# Possibility to mark state as updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm currently rebuilding and optimizing my react app, to use functional components and react hooks.
Following given code snippet:

```js
const someComponent: React.FC<someProps> = props => {

  [...]

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
  const [possibleCustomers, setPossibleCustomers] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer] = useState('');
  const [possibleOrders, setPossibleOrders] = useState<{value: string, text: string}[]>([]);
  const [selectedOrder, setSelectedOrder] = useState('');
  
  [...]

  // possibleCustomers und selectedCustomer ermitteln wenn sich selectedValue aendert
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedValue) {
      console.log('selectedValue useEffect');
      const newCustomers = determineCustomers(selectedValue);
      let newCustomer = '';
      if (newCustomers.length > 0) {
        newCustomer = (newCustomers.indexOf(selectedCustomer) > -1) ?
          selectedCustomer :
          newCustomers[0];
      };
      setPossibleCustomers(newCustomers);
      setSelectedCustomer(newCustomer);
    };
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [selectedValue]);

  // possibleOrders und selectedOrder ermitteln wenn sich selectedCustomer aendert
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedCustomer) {
      console.log('selectedCustomer useEffect');
      const newOrders = determineOrders(selectedValue, selectedCustomer);
      let newOrder = '';
      if (newOrders.length > 0) {
        newOrder = (newOrders.findIndex(o => o.value === selectedOrder) > -1) ?
          selectedOrder :
          newOrders[0].value;
      };
      setPossibleOrders(newOrders);
      setSelectedOrder(newOrder);
    };
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [selectedCustomer]);
  
  [...]
  
  return (
    <>
    
      [...]

          <IonItem>
            <IonLabel position="fixed">Label 1</IonLabel>
            <IonSelect
              onIonChange={(e: { target?: any; }) => setSelectedValue(e.target.value)}
              value={selectedValue} okText="Okay"
              cancelText="Schließen" className="fullWidth"
            >
              {masterData?.values && masterData.values.map(i => (
                <IonSelectOption key={i.value} value={i.value}>{i.text}</IonSelectOption>
              ))}
            </IonSelect>
          </IonItem>
          <IonItem>
            <IonLabel position="fixed">Label 2</IonLabel>
            <IonSelect
              onIonChange={(e: { target?: any; }) => setSelectedCustomer(e.target.value)}
              value={selectedCustomer} okText="Okay"
              cancelText="Schließen" className="fullWidth"
            >
              {possibleCustomers.map(i => (
                <IonSelectOption key={i} value={i}>{i}</IonSelectOption>
              ))}
            </IonSelect>
          </IonItem>
    
      [...]

    </>
  );
};
```

The user has the possibility to select `selectedValue` and `selectedCustomer`. For both of them there is an `useEffect` which handles their state changes and determines some stuff.
**Now I've the following problem:** If the user selects a `selectedValue` which yields the same `selectedCustomer`as before, `setSelectedCustomer` doesn't trigger the `useEffect` for `selectedCustomer` (the correct way of working). But in this case it has to execute, cause `determineOrders` expects `selectedValue` and `selectedCustomer` as parameter.
Due to the fact of the customer-`useEffect` depends on data of the value-`useEffect`, I can't simply change the dependencies of the customer-`useEffect` to `[selectedCustomer, selectedValue]` (because of the async working of `setSelectedCustomer`).

Is there any option that I can mark the state of `selectedCustomer` as updated, although the value doesn't change? So the `useEffect`executes. Or any other ideas?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**
Got following workaround, but maybe anyone has a cleaner solution.

```js
  [...]

  const [forceCustomerEffect, setForceCustomerEffect] = useState(false);

  [...]

      if (newCustomer === selectedCustomer) {
        setForceCustomerEffect(!forceCustomerEffect); // egal, ob true oder false gesetzt wird!
      };
      setPossibleCustomers(newCustomers);
      setSelectedCustomer(newCustomer);

  [...]

  }, [selectedCustomer, forceCustomerEffect]);

  [...]
```

Comment: You have a lot going on here, but in short, add `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` to your ESLint setup and you'll see that you are not declaring all of the actual dependencies for your `useEffect` hooks. The last one alone should probably be `[determineOrders, selectedValue, selectedCustomer, selectedOrder, setPossibleOrders, setSelectedOrder]`, but you just have `[selectedCustomer]`.

Comment: Yes actually I disabled it with `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`, cause I don't want to execute it that much. Only if one of the both values have changed. And additionally if I would add them, it wouldn't properly work because of the async `setSelectedCustomer`:/

Comment: If you don't declare the dependencies here your function is going to be acting on stale data (and keeping it from being garbage collected). You probably need to re-think your approach. Maybe this should be a function that is called to change the customer instead of acting like an observer?

Comment: Yes, maybe I have to rethink this behaviour:/ I was hoping for a simple solution.
And acutally it would be pretty cool if you could mark a state as updated:D

Comment: Added a new state  `forceCustomerEffect` to the component.